# How can I fix the Aloha HTML5 Editor to a specific position on the page?

Tags: html, aloha-editor

I need the Aloha editor to be pinned to a specific position instead of bouncing around all over the page.

Is there a configuration option for that? There is an "append" option for configuring Aloha but I can't figure out how to apply or even if it would solve my problem...

Also open to hacks for overriding the position if there isn't a configuration option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response to my bug report:

> This setting was added to the dev branch (but has not found it's way
>   to the release branch so far) and the description for it in the guides
>   was already added to the release branch.

https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/issues/584#issuecomment-6870029

Answer (score 3):

The [configuration](http://aloha-editor.org/guides/configure_aloha.html) indicates that you use an the "element" setting to specify the id of the element to append to:

```
behaviour: 'float', // 'float' (default), 'topalign', 'append'
element: 'my-html-element-id', // use with 'append' behaviour option: HTML DOM ID of the element the FM should get the position from
```

Also, make use of the other options like draggable: false and pin: false.

If that doesn't work for you, please open a [bugreport](https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/issues).

Comment: I tried those settings but unfortunately they don't seem to affect the display of the editor.

Comment: In fact, no changes made to Aloha.settings.floatingmenu are being respected... adjustments made via Aloha.settings.sidebar for example are applied but Aloha.settings.floatingmenu doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: submitted bugreport here, fyi: https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/issues/584

Answer (score 0):

```
var toolbar = $('.aloha-toolbar');
// make the toolbar extend to 100% of the div.
toolbar.css({'width': '100%', 'height': '100%', });
// ADDS THE ALOHA EDITOR TO A DIV! 
$('#alohaContainer').append(toolbar);
// Renders the toolbar to the screen             
UiPlugin.showToolbar();
// The child element must also be resized, don't know why
toolbar.children().css({'width': '100%', 'height': '100%'});
```